# How do i show animation on top screen when navigation bar is present?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation

I want to show the animation above the navigation header bar..

But it is showing under the header bar.

I used zIndex also but it is not working.

I have also attached a picture of the result that I am getting.

This is in App.js in this I have just set up the screen for navigation

```
import MainScreen from "./screens/MainScreen";
import SecondScreen from "./screens/SecondScreen";
import ThirdScreen from "./screens/ThirdScreen";
import FourthScreen from "./screens/FourthScreen";

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({

  FourthScreen: {
    screen: FourthScreen
  },
  SecondScreen: {
    screen: SecondScreen,
  },
  ThirdScreen: {
    screen: ThirdScreen
  },
  MainScreen: {
    screen: MainScreen
  }

})

const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default App;
```

In FourthScreen.js, this is the screen where is want to do animation..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, Animated, View} from "react-native";


class FourthScreen extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Screen Title",
        headerTitleStyle: {
            textAlign: "center",
            flex: 1
          },
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
         this.position = new Animated.ValueXY(0,0);
        Animated.spring(this.position, {
            toValue: {x: 0, y: -50}
        }).start();
    }

    render() { 
        return (
            <Animated.View style={this.position.getLayout()}>
                <View style= {styles.ball} />
            </Animated.View>
         );
    }
}

const styles = {
    ball: {
        height: 60,
        width: 60,
        borderRadius: 30,
        borderWidth: 30,
        borderColor: "black",
        zIndex: 100,
        position: "absolute"
    }
}

export default FourthScreen;
```

[image: This is the initial State of the circle that I want to do navigation]

[image: End result is this]

[image: I want my result something like this --initial position]

[image: this is result]

Comment: Can you print some print screen of actual result?

Comment: link for screen : https://i.stack.imgur.com/b67X7.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtWLv.png

Comment: This circle is this animations which you want to add upper then nav bar?

Comment: i have added another image.. I want me thing like that..  i want to show animation above of the navigation bar

Comment: I think, you can store some variable in navigation component and change it to these animations witch redux saga

Comment: can you show me how? Is redux necessary ?? I just want to show that animation